# Deliberatly downgrade Android device perfomance

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing

For purpose of research I would like to downgrade performance of my high-end Android device (Samsung). By downgrading performance I would like to emulate certain device problems such as CPU overloading or RAM problems or Network interface problems, basically any problem that can negatively effect Android app performance. Also, by degrading performance I could emulate usage of older Android devices. Any suggestions on how can I achieve such degradations?

Comment: Searching individually... just some clues... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396766/how-can-i-stress-my-phones-cpu-programatically and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282021/ways-of-increasing-memory-usage-of-android-app-programmatically